# How to change the font size with Sass in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I am getting crisscross information and wanted to raise the issue here. I have read in some places the font size should be changed from the html element for example:

```
html { font-size: 14px }
```

And the bootstrap 4 rem values will update the text accordingly.

Interestingly if I keep the html element's font-size to its default and change the bootstrap variables to change the font size, am I doing something wrong?

For example:

```
html { font-size: 16px }

// Changing bootstrap variable to 
$font-size-base: 0.875rem //instead of 1rem
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

With all the confusion and so many different answers. I approached the authors of bootstrap with the question to clear it up once and for all.

It is now crystal that we will need to change **$font-size-base** which will directly change the root font-size.

I was also advised by their contributor to not control the font-size with html element rather change the bootstrap's variable instead.

REF: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/24060

## Caution about using just CSS override

using the supplied css example will not work for all aspects of bootstrap sizing.

The compiled result of scss uses the `$font-size-base` variable to size many things and may be used in more areas in the future.

[List of sized elements](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/search?q=%24font-size-base&unscoped_q=%24font-size-base)

- dropdown font
- button font
- popover font
- input-group font
- forms font
- reboot font

## --------------  Example SCSS  --------------

This is an example for your scss files, note that you need to define the `$font-size-base` BEFORE including bootstrap in your main scss file. In this case, the `app.scss` file is the one being compiled.

app.scss

```
// Fonts
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,600");

// Variables -- this is where you defined the variables 
//              BEFORE importing bootstrap which will use it's  
//              defaults if the variable is not predefined.
@import "variables";
// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
// DataTables https://datatables.net/download/npm#DataTables-core
// @import "datatables";
@import "datatables.min";
```

_variables.scss

```
// Body
$body-bg: #ffffff;

// Typography
$font-size-base: 12px; // this changes the font-size throughout bootstrap
$font-family-sans-serif: "Raleway", sans-serif;
$font-size-base: 0.9rem;
$line-height-base: 1.6;
```

Comment: A good article: https://coursetro.com/posts/design/73/How-to-Customize-Bootstrap-4-with-Sass

Comment: You find a list of all variables here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss

Comment: $font-size-base is defined twice, once in rem and once in px. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: Changing `$font-size-base` to a pixel value rather than a rem value does not even compile scss styles,  I could not find anything that supports it is better than `html { font-size: 12px; }`

Comment: it looks like the display-* classes don't honour the $font-size-base unfortunately https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L311

Comment: This is something that probably needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Bootstrap defines base `font-size` in it's `_reboot.scss` as

```
body {
    font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #292b2c;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

**NOTE:-** Never change default values into frameworks files always modify values using custom css/js files.

so in order to change your font-size to `14px` use this in your own `style.css`(custom css file)

```
body {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
 }
```

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhavikbamania/a8xn5bo3/1/)

use `!important` you are not able to see your changes to override your change on default.

In your `custom.scss` file do like this:

```
$custom-variable:0.875rem;
```

Then use it like this:

```
@import "./src/scss/_modules/custom"; 
@import "./bower_components/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

body {
font-size:$custom-variable;
}
```

Comment: Yes I am using overrides, I never would change anything in the core files...its basic common sense... But that doesn't really answer my question... why can I not change the base values in bootstrap variable using override method?

Comment: so I am pulling in the bootstrap source with @import then I am using a custom file to modify the variables (leaving bootstrap files untouched).

Comment: yeah in custom css file you can add this code to modify it after `@import` however you can directly add resouces like mentioned in bootstrap docs. and at the last of your can your custom to override default with your custom css.

Comment: So you are saying as long as I change the variables using a separate file (for obvious reasons); this should be ok? If you change your answer to reflect that I will accept.

Comment: My question is directly related to changing the bootstrap variable using an external file. So in essence I am not altering the bootstrap files rather using the _custom.scss to change base font of bootstrap. So instead of 1rem I am going to use 0.875rem; Doing it will not lose any functionality of bootstrap. If you are saying I should not change the base font size of bootstrap, can you back up your theory as to why?

Comment: check it now I got confused with `$font-size-base` and thought you have this variable I hope I got you right.

Comment: some time we must change in file
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53123544/how-to-customize-bootstrap-4-sass-with-npm-in-laravel

Comment: You can but add your own class along with it so that you can preserve your default value. changing directly into files is what I won't recommend any one to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to update directly the `html {font-size: 16px}` property instead of changing Bootstrap's `$font-size-base`, for several reasons:

1. `html`'s font size will be directly used in calculating final font size. There's no benefit to use an *"intermediary"*, that is, `body` that is being adjusted by Bootstrap's `$font-size-base`.
2. Bootstrap's SCSS system calculate heading size etc using `$font-size-base`, so all Bootstrap affected CSS rule will be affected, which includes `body` (set into `$font-size-base$`).
   However, browser calculate any CSS font size rule in `rem` relative to `html {font-size}`, *not* from `$font-size-base` affected elements (like `body`).
3. Setting `html {font-size}` using `px` will affect any `rem` value, both inside and outside Bootstrap affected elements, if this is what you want to achieve.

Conversely, if you only want to set sizes for Bootstrap-affected-elements, *do* set the `$font-size-base` relative to `html {font-size}`, so CSS elements outside of Bootstrap will *not* be affected. But I'd say this is more of an edge case, instead of the norm.

Note:
If you're setting `$font-size-base` or any other Bootstrap variables, you don't have to modify `variables.scss` file. You should define variables *before* importing `node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables` and other Bootstrap files, so your values got used instead of `!default` values set in Bootstrap. The advantages: no need to edit the whole `variables.scss` file.

Comment: I added this answer due to previous answers not considering use case where CSS rule of elements _not_ affected by Bootstrap (which IMO is the norm), and also adding suggestion on overriding default Bootstrap variables in what I consider the most practical way (example using NPM / NodeJS workflow).